# Taking advantage of his present?

Tags: sentence-construction

***Taking advantage of his present popularity, the Prime Minister called an election.***

Can we write this sentence like this? or is this sentence an adverb manner sentence Why?

The Prime Minister ***who took advantage*** of his present popularity called an election. ?

Comment: No. Your example selects the PM who did that from others who didn't. You want - "The Prime Minister *took advantage* of his present popularity **by calling** an election." And present is an adjective (like momentary or current), not adverb.

Comment: By adverbial style, I mean "Taking advantage of his present popularity ''

Comment: Maybe "**Presently** taking advantage ...", but I don't yet see the adverb **clearly**